# How to enlarge image without distorting it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixelation

I would like to double the size of this image without causing any pixelization.

Can you please let me know how can it be done?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's going to largely depend on the original size. Photoshop is many things, but it's not magic. It can do some fairly impressive things with pixel interpolation but there's a limit.

I would suggest using "Image" -> "Image Size..." and scaling it that way - at least it will scale consistently. I am not quite sure how exact you need to be when you say "any" pixelation; this method may allow you to scale this with a minimum (i.e., not noticeable by anyone who's not looking for it) amount.

If you're *really* worried about this I'd create it in a vector-based program like Illustrator (it looks like it'd be a fairly simple job) so you can scale it to any size your heart desires.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea how can I create it in Illustrator? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

With this particular image, I'd scale it up with Image Size at 200%, using bicubic interpolation, and then correct the issues.

The only areas where pixelation will be noticeable will be:

- the arrow symbol. Was that based on a dingbat font symbol? If so, should be easy to recreate.
- the right hand angled outline. Copy a rectangular area from just left of the arrow symbol over the scaled-up right hand end, then use the polygon select tool to delete from this leaving a crisp edge. Angles look to be 45deg which will male it easier.
- possibly the dividing line between the two types of fill. Copying and pasting will fix this.

Comment: Doesn't apply to this particular graphic, but Fireworks' 9-slice-scaling is also pretty handy for resizing rectangular objects while preserving edges and corners.